# Ruby map specific hash keys to new one

Tags: ruby, hash

I've got an array full of hashes of which I want to combine specific keys to a new one, e.g.

```
[{ firstname: 'john', lastname: 'doe', something: 'else', key: ... }, { firstname: 'Joe', lastname: 'something', something: 'bla', key:... }]
```

should become

```
[{ name: 'john doe' },{ name: 'Joe something' }]
```

Please note: there are more keys in the hash as first and lastname. Is there a common ruby method to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do as

```
array = [{ firstname: 'john', lastname: 'doe' }, { firstname: 'Joe', lastname: 'something' }]
array.map { |h| { :name => h.values_at(:firstname, :lastname) * " " } }
# => [{:name=>"john doe"}, {:name=>"Joe something"}]
```

Read this [`Hash#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [`Array#*`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-2A) .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer as well as the additional links! By the way, what exactly did you edit in my question?

Comment: @LinusAn You missed last `"` in `'Joe something'`.. So I fixed

Comment: I'm sorry I just noticed the example in my question was a little bit wrong. I corrected it as follows and hope you could answer it as well. The result should combine the two keys as well as keep all other keys.

Comment: @LinusAn You keep please your post how it was previously.. Otherwise my answer seems totally wrong. The future of my answer will be very bad. So please revert it. put your new requirement in a separate post.

Comment: @LinusAn Join this [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54561/room-for-arup-rakshit-and-tadman).. The other answer, which still you have in mind, I will give there.. Please join

Answer (score 2):

This is:

```
a = [{ firstname: 'john', lastname: 'doe' }, { firstname: 'Joe', lastname: 'something' }]
a.map { |n| { name: n.values.join(' ') } }
# => [{:name=>"john doe"}, {:name=>"Joe something"}]
```

Comment: This won't work as I have more than two keys in each hash, right? But thank you nevertheless.

Comment: Sure. Sorry, I skipped your note. :)

Comment: It's not your fault, I realize my example was wrong. It didn't show that these other keys remain in the result hashes / array. I correted it.